# Which characters (not) to use for IDs (R)

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, uniqueidentifier

I'm currently writing a function in R that creates IDs that are as short as possible because I work with quite large data (a few hundret million cases) and the IDs are unnecessary long which costs very much space. I'm using the function `combinations`from the package `arrangements` and for this I want to use as many unique characters as possible. Of course, `letters`, `LETTERS` and `0:9` but I also want to use some other characters. Are there any characters that are problematic for this? For example for encoding or because they are special letters? I'd only use "common" characters like !, §, $, %, &, /, (, ) or =.

Comment: I would recommend using the `uuid` package, where it has it's own UUID generator function. It only uses lowercase, numbers and "-" but is very useful.

EDIT: Just noticed the size constraint. The generator does have a time parameter and can substring the first part of the ID (which is affected by short amounts of time)